# Unistall and Install in one seamless process using installshield 2012.

Tags: installation, installshield, uninstallation

I have been researching about uninstalling older version of application and installing new one after that. I am pretty new with installshield. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is called a "Major Upgrade". InstallShield has a series of help topics on the subject.

Comment: Can i keep the product code same in every version change upgrade? Plus  I am using 4 digit version number instead of 3. Does it affect major upgrade?